# Error binding files to model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm having trouble binding my file inputs correctly to my model, on form post.
I'm trying to bind to the model below.

The reason for using the FileWrapper class, that practically is a substitute for a dictionary, is just to try out something different than a dictionary, because i couldn't get that working either. If its possible with a Dictionary, i'll be happy to change it back.

What i need is to be able to bind several MULTIPLE file inputs to different file lists. Hence why the FileWrapper has an `IENumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`. The reason for having the FileWrappers in a list, is because the numbers of file inputs may vary. The View is generated dynamically.

When i try to bind like this, the index looks like it binds correctly, but the file list is empty.

Please let me know if i can provide something extra.

The form inputs looks like this:

Html

```
<input type="hidden" name="FileWrappers[0].Index" value="0" />
<input type="file" name="FileWrappers[0].Files" multiple>
```

Model

```
public class SpecialBeregningModel
{        
    public List<FileWrapper> FileWrappers { get; set; }

    public SpecialBeregningModel()
    {
        FileWrappers = new List<FileWrapper>();
    }
}

public class FileWrapper
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFile> Files { get; set; }

    public FileWrapper()
    {
        Files = new List<HttpPostedFile>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property should be `HttpPostedFileBase`, not `HttpPostedFile`:

```
public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
```

Also don't forget `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on the containing `<form>`.

Comment: Well, that's not embarrassing at all! I did indeed forget to use The FileBase (Copy paste typo). thanks